# How to NAT virtual interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, interface, virtualization, nat

I've created a virtual interface in Ubuntu with the following:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.1.99 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

Now I need to be able to ping from the new virtual interface.

```
ping -I 192.168.1.99 www.google.co.in
```

I am unable to do that. I have enabled IP forwarding.

Comment: please provide netstat -nr output

Answer (score 0):

The `ping -I` option should just work, I might be mistaken but it works out-of-the-box in the examples below, and ive not enabled forwarding. Can you provide your `ifconfig` and `netstat -r` output.

Normally the source IP would be set depending on the network interface for the appropriate route for the target address, so if `eth0:0` was also an appropriate IP for the interface you end up with 1 of 2 possibilities like so;

1. for example, if my ip address is 192.168.1.72 like so;

   ```
   # ifconfig  
   eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:04:4B:16:BA:41   
             inet addr:192.168.1.72  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
   ```

   and I add another IP address, like your command;

   ```
   ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.1.99 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
   ```

   then I would end up with the following

   ```
   # ifconfig
   eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:04:4B:16:BA:41  
             inet addr:192.168.1.72  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

   eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:04:4B:16:BA:41  
             inet addr:192.168.1.99  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
   ```

   so I can ping with either the default IP bound to the eth0 interface;

   ```
   ping -I 192.168.1.72 myremote.host.com

   echo request...  
   echo reply....
   ```

   or the new one;

   ```
   ping -I 192.168.1.99 myremote.host.com

   echo request...  
   echo reply....
   ```

   but because,  192.168.1.xx are all local addresses behind a NAT'ted connection, the remote host at `myremote.host.com` just sees your external IP and not `192.168.1.72`:

   ```
   20:24:21.452732 IP 87.19.24.187 > 123.123.123.123: ICMP echo request, id 49711, seq 6, length 64
   20:24:21.452757 IP 123.123.123.123 > 87.19.24.187: ICMP echo reply, id 49711, seq 6, length 64
   ```

   > where `87.19.24.187` is the public address
2. However if I set some crazy IP address to the interface, like so;

   ```
   ifconfig eth0:2 192.192.7.99 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
   ```

   my remote host sees the ping, but the client never gets the reply;

   ```
   # tcpdump -nn icmp and host xxx
   tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
   listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
   20:25:01.165321 IP xxx > yyy: ICMP echo request, id 49730, seq 1, length 64
   20:25:01.165349 IP yyy > xxx: ICMP echo reply, id 49730, seq 1, length 64
   ```